# Can the internal tester in testflight use the build even if he is removed from the testers list?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, testflight

I have uploaded a build to TestFlight and we have 3 testers in it and they have installed the app in their devices via TestFlight invitation. Now i am planning to upload another build but this build should be available only for 2 testers so i am planning to delete one tester from the TestFlight testers list for this specific app. We are not deleting the tester from our iTunes Connect Users List.   If i am trying to delete tester from the list it is showing the below message.

[image]

So my doubt is, if i am deleting the tester from the list whether he will be able to use the app which is already installed in his device from testflight. I want the tester to use the app.

I am aware of creating groups in testflight for testing but we can only create group for external testers, we cannot create a group for internal testers. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If they have the app already installed they will be able to use it since it is not launched via *TestFlight*. What they won't be able to do is to download new versions or use it after it expires.

You can read more about how TestFlight policies work [here](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/), and [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/29984#29984) there is a discussion about expired builds.

Comment: Have you ever came through this situation? Since i cant take a chance.

Comment: yes, I am used to TestFlight for validation with external users before shipping :)

Comment: also, if removing access to users from your app is so important, you should consider on developing a method to revoke their access with a service of your own instead of relying on third-party access control